# i can't install gradlew

Tags: java, eclipse

I cant install gradlew eclipse.Here is log error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Someone know how to fix this?

I many times tried to reinstall JDK, used official JDK and eclipse adoptium, tried every gradlew version before 7.0 (because MDK 1.12.2 don't use above), but it always crashes with message above.
Also Eclipse has this error:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip'.
Unable to make protected java.lang.Package[] java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6267890e    MyMod       line 0  Gradle Error Marker

Comment: There may be compatibility issue with gradle and Java version, from log I can deduce that you are using Java version > 8 and gradlew wrapper version 4.9. check compatibility here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

Comment: Nowadays, `gradlew eclipse` should not needed at all.